# CUDA remote GPU

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to create virtual cuda gpu and execute cuda commands on another server?

Architecture:

```
server_1                 server_2
virtual_gpu --> data --> cuda_device
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rcuda](http://www.rcuda.net) should do what you are looking for, although I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thank you! This project fully fit.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant as the rCUDA website seems to have come to a sudden halt in 2020 due to COVID?  Am I right in assuming this is now part of (or superseded by) PyTorch NCCL backend and not some separate project?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you set up an instance to run on each machine,
using a shared network folder, making sure they don't overwrite eachother.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV0eXkLDqjE